# SPARQL - query Getty database (ULAN - Union List of Artist Names) to get all artists

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I try to figure out how to work with SPARQL queries and the Getty database: http://vocab.getty.edu/sparql

I try to receive all artists from the database (ulan, name, bio, nationality, type of artist):

```
select ?x ?name ?bio ?nationality ?type {
  ?x gvp:broaderExtended ulan:500000002. # Persons, Artists
  optional {?x gvp:agentTypePreferred [gvp:prefLabelGVP [xl:literalForm ?type]]}
  optional {?x foaf:focus [gvp:nationalityPreferred [gvp:prefLabelGVP [xl:literalForm ?nationality]]]}
  optional {?x gvp:prefLabelGVP [xl:literalForm ?name]}
  optional {?x foaf:focus [gvp:biographyPreferred [schema:description ?bio]]}
}
```

But how can I retrieve the nationality as iso code (ex. "de", "us", "fr" etc.)? 
I have no clue how I can learn about which properties a type of the ontology has. Is there an overview where I can lookup the properties of a type? F.e. I don't know why the `foaf:focus` property has itself a property called `gvp:nationalityPreferred` and where to find that information.

Comment: This ontology looks complicated... Start from here: http://vocab.getty.edu/doc/#ULAN_Nationalities . BTW, `foaf:focus` doesn't have the `gvp:nationalityPreferred` property, it has a value, which has this property: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynBlankNodes

Comment: You can only query for data that is contained in the dataset. Is the ISO country code in the dataset? If not, you can't do it with SPARQL and have to use client side code to map from nationality to ISO code.

Comment: `BIND (strlang(replace(str(?nationality), " (.*)$", ""), "en") AS ?demonym)` gives you something like `"Dutch"@en`. Then `[ wdt:P1549 ?demo ; wdt:P297 ?iso2 ] . filter (lang(?demo) = 'en')` on Wikidata gives you mapping to ISO codes. But it seems that http://vocab.getty.edu/sparql doesn't support federated queries: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gettyvocablod/bQhQOdXSlgY.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try to use a second query after I obtained data from the first (posted) query. This seems to make things easier.